# How do I generate a random image from a JavaScript array of variables into my HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, generator

This is what I have so far in my HTML and JavaScript pages, although I do not want to use a URL in the JavaScript file, since I have the images in my project folder. But when I open the html, no images pop up. I also do not want a background image.

```js
var images = ["img/1.jpg", "img/2.jpg", "img/3.jpg", "img/4.jpg", "img/5.jpg", "img/6.jpg"];

var randomName = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

document.getElementById("randomImage").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://angelinawong.com/" + randomName + "')";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>47</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="randomImage"/>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the javascript part, just make sure the image url is right (these are all pointing to nowhere) and the element has some minimum width and height.

Comment: Other than the images not existing on those URL's, it seems to work fine

Comment: @adeneo don't you need also need a `randomName + 1` since the image names start at `1` ? But you are right about the `/img` urls not working. I tried them too.

Comment: @82Tuskers - no, the names of the images isn't relevant, just the index in the array

Comment: I have all the images on a project folder, and not on a URL. I want to get rid of the "url(..." function, but I can't

Comment: I have lots of images, so I don't want to write them out one by one. And they're not online

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the script tags after the body tag, It could be a problem with the order HTML and JS are loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>47</title></head>
<body>
 <div id="randomImage"/>
</body>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! I think that was the problem. Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to generate those images, and since I don't want to use a URL, how to replace the "url" with the path of a project folder?

Comment: @Angelina You can use relative urls from the location where your `index.html` is present.